# Usage of dyn in rust

Tags: rust

Boxes allow you to store data on the heap rather than the stack. What remains on the stack is the pointer to the heap data.

```
// Returns some struct that implements Animal, but we don't know which one at compile time.
fn random_animal(random_number: f64) -> Box<dyn Animal> {
    if random_number < 0.5 {
        Box::new(Sheep {})
    } else {
        Box::new(Cow {})
    }
}
```

If box is anyways providing a pointer to the Heap data, and pointer size will be the same for both the struct on stack, why we can just return `Box<Animal>` from this function?
I wish to know why I cannot write `Box<Animal>` instead of `Box<dyn Animal>`?

Comment: Can you be more specific on your concern? Do you wish to know why you can write `Box<Animal>` instead of `Box<dyn Animal>`?

Comment: Made changes and yes, this is exactly my question.

Comment: They are equivalent. The `dyn` keyword was made to avoid confusion between a trait (`Foo`) and its trait type (`dyn Foo`).